# How to build using SBT in offline mode

Tags: maven, sbt, offline, ivy

What is the equivalent of `mvn -o` in SBT? When I check my .ivy repository, I can see the dependecy jars in `cache/groupId/artifactId/jars`. When I try to build it without internet connection, it still does this `Resolving ...` thing and shows Unresolved Dependencies error. How can I turn this off? I tried using `sbt set-offline := true` but still gets the error. Is this possible? Maybe download once and save the artifacts in .m2 like maven and get it from there if its not possible in .ivy

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you got absolutely all your dependencies ?

- dependencies for SBT => downloaded when SBT starts
- plugins dependencies => downloaded during project loading
- Project dependencies => downloaded when the related tasks are started, e.g. compile time deps on 'compile', test deps on 'test', etc...

Comment: Yes. I tried it online and offline consecutively. I also noticed that the errors only occurred when doing an `sbt clean compile` but not in `sbt compile` only. Is this the expected behavior? Does sbt has an equivalent for `mvn -o clean compile`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `set skip in update := true`