# How to switch sbt to offline mode

Tags: sbt, offline-mode

## The questions

1. Why offline still needs external http access?
2. How to enable a proper offline mode

## Problem

Inside sbt/activator I'm executing:

```
compile
set offline := true
clean
compile
```

- Having internet connection:

  - First compiles successfully.
  - Second compiles successfully.
- After I remove the internet connection.

  - First compile fails.
  - Second compile fails but a little faster :D

The failure is

```
[namek] $ compile
[info] Updating {file:/D:/personal/work2/namek/}namekServerPrj...
[info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;2.1.0 ...
[error] Server access Error: No route to host: connect url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0/spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.pom
[error] Server access Error: No route to host: connect url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0/spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.pom
[error] Server access Error: No route to host: connect url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: No route to host: connect url=http://dl.bintray.com/raisercostin/maven/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0/spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;2.1.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\costin\.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.11\2.1.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   C:\apps\activator\repository\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.11\2.1.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   C:\apps\activator\repository\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.11\2.1.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0/spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0/spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== raisercostin resolver: tried
[warn]   http://dl.bintray.com/raisercostin/maven/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0/spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.pom
```

---

A similar topic that wasn't helpful [How to build using SBT in offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061342/how-to-build-using-sbt-in-offline-mode)